# Laravel: Change Projects root directory

Tags: php, laravel

I have xampp installed - apache and mysql are running.

When I create a new laravel project via command:
laravel new projectname

It creates it in: C:/Users/MyUser/

How do I change that directory?

Comment: It'll make it in whatever directory you're in when you run the command. Use `cd` to go somewhere else first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cd ../some-other-directory

laravel new projectname
```

Comment: cd D:\Laravel
laravel new projectname

still creates in the same place

Comment: @MaximLaco To change the drive typ just `D:` (+enter) first