# Laravel won't direct localhost to my project

Tags: php, laravel, localhost

I want to open my project from the browser when I enter "localhost" instead of "localhost/projectname/public/index.php". How will I do that?

I checked my httpd.conf file in apache\conf\ and it says in this certain section:

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/projectname"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/projectname">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: without project name you don't open direct your porject on localhost

Comment: try adding /public/ after your projectname. It should point to the index inside it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel: Change Projects root directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27948065/laravel-change-projects-root-directory)

Comment: Simplier is to use php build-in php server. Just navigate to public folder of your project from console and run php -S localhost:8080.

Comment: what I mean is instead of entering "localhost/projectname/..." which is very long, I want to just enter "localhost" in my browser to open my project. I did it before but I forgot how to so my previous project was the one always opening. btw, im using laravel 4.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by other users a simpler approach might be to just use the [built in php server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php)